# (Fixed)JTable does not add a new row

Tags: java, swing

My project is to create a small temporary database with users and their passwords, so everything is saved in a second window, which would have a JTable and a button return to the main window. The problem would be precisely in JTable, when registering a new user, it ends up replacing the first user and so on, and a new row is not added with its respective registration.

Main:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.JPasswordField;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class LoginGUI {

    private static JPanel panel;
    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JLabel userLabel, passwordLabel;
    private static JPasswordField passwordText;
    private static JTextField userText;
    private static JButton buttonRegister, buttonShow;
    private static JLabel success;
    //This is just for print in the console
    private static final LinkedList<DataUser> array = new LinkedList();
    private static String user, pass;
    private static DataUser listUser;
    private static Show show = new Show(); //Problem solved by instantiating this first

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Panel
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(350, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        //User
        userLabel = new JLabel("User");
        userLabel.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25);
        panel.add(userLabel);

        //Password
        passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 50, 80, 25);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);

        //Password TextField
        passwordText = new JPasswordField();
        passwordText.setBounds(100, 50, 165, 25);
        panel.add(passwordText);

        //User TextField
        userText = new JTextField(20);
        userText.setBounds(100, 20, 165, 25);
        panel.add(userText);

        //Register Button
        buttonRegister = new JButton("Login");
        buttonRegister.setBounds(10, 90, 80, 25);
        panel.add(buttonRegister);
        RegisterButtonListener registerButtonListener = new RegisterButtonListener();
        buttonRegister.addActionListener(registerButtonListener);

        //Show list Button
        buttonShow = new JButton("Show list");
        buttonShow.setBounds(100, 90, 100, 25);
        panel.add(buttonShow);
        ShowButtonListener showButtonListener = new ShowButtonListener();
        buttonShow.addActionListener(showButtonListener);

        //Login successful
        success = new JLabel("");
        success.setBounds(100, 110, 300, 25);
        panel.add(success);

        //Panel visible
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //ActionListener for register
    public static class RegisterButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            user = userText.getText();
            pass = passwordText.getText();
            listUser = new DataUser(user, pass);
            array.add(listUser);
            System.out.println(array);
            success.setText("Registration added!");
        }
    }

    //ActionListener for show list
    public static class ShowButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //show = new Show();(This was the problem)
            show.setUser(user);
            show.setPass(pass);
            show.saveData();
            show.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

DataUser:

```
public class DataUser {

    private final String user;
    private final String pass;
    private final String breakLine = "";

    public DataUser(String user, String pass) {
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(breakLine).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        return "User: " + user + " | Pass: " + pass
                + sb.toString();
    }
}
```

And the new JFrame where is the JTable: [JTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nURXM.png)

Code (Problem is probably in the saveData() method):

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public final class Show extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    DefaultTableModel table;
    private final String[][] matrix = {};
    String head[] = {"User", "Pass"};
    private String user, pass;

    public Show() {
        initComponents();
        table = new DefaultTableModel(matrix, head);
        jTable.setModel(table);
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public void saveData() { //Problem is probably here
        String data[] = {getUser(), getPass()};
        table.addRow(data);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "User", "Pass"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("<- Return");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "Title1", "Title2"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable);
        if (jTable.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
            jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
        }

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 376, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 275, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    //Return Button
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        dispose();
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Show.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Show.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Show.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Show.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Show().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Comment: So, a number of issues.  `ShowButtonListener` is creating a new instance of the `Show` frame and it only knows about the last user it was assigned.  You could test this by tapping the show button a number of times. This "could" be fixed with a independent model which maintained the data itself and was feed to the `Show` class instead.  You should avoid using `null` layouts and absolute positioning, I run on MacOS and your first windows layout was a mess.  I'd consider using a `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame` for the `Show` class, but that would depend on your intentions

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"You should avoid using `null` layouts"* I had been looking at the `Show` class (which uses `GroupLayout`) and your comment confused me until I saw the `LoginGUI`. .. Quite a contrast in strategies!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yep 

Comment: Omg, very right in the instance, thank you very much, I can improve a little more on some projects right now!

Comment: *"very right in the instance"* Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.